# contador que debe recorrer 600 array

Tags: c++, c, arduino

buen día gente, tengo un problema que me esta costando solucionar ..... estoy probando crear 600 arrays de un tamaño de 600, para almacenar la informació de una señal digital llamada DATA, es  tomada solo cuando hay una interrupción dada por otra señal.

la idea es que guarde la información y luego pase al siguiente array ..así sucesivamente y se detenga e imprima los resultados cuando llegue a el array #600.

el problema que no se me ocurre como solucionar es crear una especie de contador que recorra los array cuando tenga que medirlos .

Estoy utilizando un arduino DUE

```
int a1[600];
int a2[600];
int a3[600];
int a4[600];
int a5[600];
.....
.....
int a597[600];
int a598[600];
int a599[600];
int a600[600];

const byte interruptPin = 2;
int cont = 1;

void setup() {
pinMode(3, INPUT);    // data
//pinMode(4, INPUT); // yb

//Serial.begin(9600);
attachInterrupt(interruptPin, contador, FALLING);

}

void loop() {
if (cont ==600) {
 SerialUSB.print(a + 
  }

}

void contador () {
  cont = cont +1 ;
  
}
```

Comment: ¿Y no sería mejor: `int listaDeArrays[600][600];` en vez de escribir 600 declaraciones del mismo tipo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los arrays

```
int a[600];
```

se crean en la pila del programa ... y eso puede ser un problema.

Cada uno de tus arrays ocupa `600*4=2400 B => 2.3 KB`. Tienes 600 arrays, luego la memoria total consumida asciende a aproximadamente 1.4 MB. Teniendo en cuenta que las pilas de los programas suelen tener, como mucho 1MB de capacidad ... pues como que no van a entrar los arrays.

Para gestionar volúmenes de información de tamaño medio/grande es imperativo el uso de memoria dinámica.

Vale, eso por un lado, ahora tu necesitas gestionar 600 arrays diferentes. Pues bien, si aislas cada array en una variable diferente, no vas a tener disponible, en principio, ningún mecanismo que te permita cambiar de uno a otro.

Esto es debido a que ni en C ni en C++ existen metadatos que le permitan al programa relacionar, en tiempo de ejecución, el nombre de una variable con su dirección de memoria.

Tendrías que mapear todos los arrays:

```
int* mega_array[600] = { &a1, &a2, ..., &a600 };
```

Si estás dispuesto a codificar esto, enhorabuena por ti, pero no es una forma elegante de resolver el problema.

Lo que necesitas es crear una colección con 600 elementos, siendo cada elemento un array con capacidad para 600 enteros:

```
int ** array = new int*[600];

for( int i=0; i<600; i++)
    array[i] = new int[600];
```

Ahora tienes todos los arrays bajo un mismo paraguas, lo que te permite iterar sobre ellos facilmente, como has podido ver en la inicialización

Comment: la duda que tengo ahora es como guardo la informacion en cada array, paso al siguiente array  guardo  y finalmente imprimo todos los arrays ?

Comment: @michaelespin es un array doble, luego necesitas dos índices: el primero es para elegir el array sobre el que vas a actuar, y el segundo índice referencia al elemento al que quieres acceder dentro de ese array: `datos[indice_array][indice_elemento] = /*...*/;`

Comment: dos dudas @eferion , podría crear un array de dos dimensiones, 2 columnas y 600 filas, seri algo asi :  `  int ** array = new int*[2, 600];   `    y  me confundí con  los dos indices, osea no se como integrar ambas cosas en un codigo en  arduino.  Soy neófito  :(

Comment: @michaelespin Cada dimensión requiere un puntero. Una dimensión (un array), puntero simple; una matriz, puntero doble. 3 dimensiones: un puntero triple. Y cada dimensión tiene su propio juego de corchetes: `array[x][y][z]`

Answer (score 2):

La "*solución*" no es crear seiscientas formaciones<sup>1</sup> de seiscientos elementos, podrías crear una formación de 600×600:

```
int datos[600][600]{};
```

Y atendiendo al valor del contador sabrás en qué formación escribir:

```
for (int indice = 0; indice != 600 * 600; ++indice)
    datos[indice / 600][indice % 600] = /* lo que sea */;
```

Pero mejor olvídate de formaciones, usa contenedores de datos:

```
std::vector<int> datos;
datos.reserve(600 * 600);

for (int indice = 0; indice != 600 * 600; ++indice)
    datos.push_back(/* lo que sea */);
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Comment: dos dudas,  el ` vector `  se puede integrar en arduino ide ? y como me guardaría información en cada uno de los arrays, es decir .. como guardo información en el array 1, paso al array 2  guardo información y sucesivamente.

Comment: Si arduino compila C++, `std::vector` estará disponible. No necesitas arrays diferentes, usa un sólo array y considera que los datos de 0..599 son el primer grupo, 600..1199 el segundo, 1200..1799 el tercero, etc...